# Getting key from value in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to figure out which key has the highest value. The only way I can think of doing that is making a list of values and finding max value from the list to get the highest value. But how do I correlate that value to the key in the dictionary?

```
        d = {}
        for i in range(len(names)):
            d[i] = len(names[i])
        a = max(d.values())
```

I need to get keys from the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `max` function with a custom key argument:

```
my_dict = {'a': 10, 'b': 5, 'c': 20, 'd': 15}

max_key = max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)

print("Key with the highest value:", max_key)
```

If you dont want to use any inbuilt function like `max`
Refer the below example :

```
my_dict = {'a': 10, 'b': 5, 'c': 20, 'd': 15}

max_key = None
max_value = float('-inf')

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if value > max_value:
        max_value = value
        max_key = key

print("Key with the highest value:", max_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
names=["abc","defs","ijk"]
d = {}
for i in names:
    d[i] = len(i)

Keymax = max(zip(d.values(), d.keys()))[1]
```